# TFS Command for List of checked in files

Tags: tfs

I have "Administrator" rights in TFS. I want to see the following details

1. ChangeSet Number
2. Files Checked in
3. Date and Time of Checkin
4. Comment

Can you please help me with the TFS Command for this?

Comment: How can you call yourself a 'TFS administrator' if you don't even know that... RTFM!

Comment: :-)... I stand corrected. I have the rights as "Administrator". But please help.

Answer (score 3):

What Jim says is correct, however be advised that if you have a significant change history in that path, this process can take a long time, and (at least under TFS 2008) can eat up a lot of tempDB space on your data tier.

Therefore, if you're only interested in the last 'n' check-ins, consider using the `/stopafter` switch.  For example:

```
tf history "$/TeamProject/Path" /recursive /noprompt /format:detailed /stopafter:50
```

This will give you the most recent 50 entries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tf history $/TeamProject/Path /recursive /noprompt /format:detailed
```

Obviously you'll want to replace $/TeamProject/Path with the appropriate ItemSpec.

Comment: Getting an answer to this from Jim Lamb is like sneezing and having God say "Me bless you."  ;)

Comment: Thanks for providing the "stopafter" suggestion, Robaticus. Probably not necessary for Lijo's situation, but certainly useful for others who may come across this in their search results. :)